# What novel/tv-show featured travel to another dimension through a TV?

Tags: story-identification, tv, novel

I have this vague recollection of either a tv-show or novel where the protagonist travels to some other dimension where they become involved with some kind of game show (the closest thing I can think of is a bit like Mojoworld). They do this by turning on the tv to a normally non-tranmitting channel at a specific time one morning and somehow this allows the two worlds to sync up, I think first allowing the game show to be seen on the tv, and then transporting the protagonist to the other world. As I'm Australian I wonder if this an Australian series but might well be American. Thanks

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/232224/story-identification-ya-novel-about-the-place-things-end-up-when-theyre-lost (about the novel on which the TV show is based)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds a bit like the Australian children's show *The Finder*, also known as *Finders Keepers*, which was based on the novel *Finders Keepers* by Emily Rodda. See the description on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Finder_%28Australian_TV_series%29).

Comment: That's the one! Many thanks!