# Story identification: YA novel about the place things end up when they're lost

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

Sometime in the mid- to late-2000s, I recall reading a sort of urban-fantasy YA novel (or perhaps series?) that involved a parallel world where lost objects end up. I initially had it mixed up with memories of The Seems series, but after [asking for help identifying that one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/232193/117791) I'm thinking it was probably a different book. This is what I remember of it:

- There's a parallel world where lost items frequently end up
- There's a barrier between the worlds that on the earth side is invisible, fragmented, and small bits of it move around erratically (the barrier moving through objects and taking them to the other world is how things get lost)

  - On the otherworld side of it, the barrier is visible, stationary, and solid, and there are people whose job is to take items back through so they can be found
- There might be *something* related to TVs or TV static? I don't know any more about what it was but for some reason I keep thinking of something like that

Any help identifying this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wonder if this could be [*Finders Keepers* by Emily Rodda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finders_Keepers_(Rodda_novel))? I haven't read it, and Wikipedia doesn't have any information, but I did see the [TV adaptation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finders_Keepers_(Australian_TV_series)) which matches a couple of points:

- The teenage protagonist is invited onto a TV show on a channel that doesn't exist.
- There's a barrier between worlds which people on one side can touch
- The protagonist crosses the barrier by means of a TV set
- The game is about finding items that were lost.

Comment: From Amazon description: "Patrick's skill at a computer game earns him a place on Finders Keepers , a positively dizzy and dizzying game show transmitted from a parallel dimension, in which Finders from our dimension win valuable prizes by hunting for objects that have accidentally fallen through a barrier from the parallel universe into ours."

Comment: This sounds very much like what I remember, but lacking further information I think I'll have to get it from the library (when it reopens) and read to be sure, since some of the details are just too fuzzy to be sure!

Comment: @Hearth https://archive.org/details/finderskeepers00rodd

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Yeah, reading the cover-flap summary of that I can say it's definitely the book I remember!

Comment: The TV adaptation actually covered both the original book and its sequel, The Timekeeper.